# Uploading Files To Server Path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have:

Works locally:

`string filePath = Server.MapPath("/Content/Images/Profiles/")`
`fileToUpload.SaveAs(filePath);`

When I deploy, on my actual web server I have a few issues, and I'm certain it's to do with the path.

The path returned is:
`C:\Inetpub\vhosts\myhost.com\httpdocs\Content\Images\Profiles\TestUser.png`

Naturally, I cannot navigate to this path.

What am I missing? Should I explicitly specify the server path e.g. '\myhost.com\httpdocs\Content\Images\Profiles\'? or stick with 'MapPath'?

Comment: That is probably the correct path. Can you describe the issues? It could simply be that you have not granted write permissions to the directory so that you can actually save the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark, unfortunately I'm yet to master the 'Plesk' directory structure and access assignments, there doesn't really seem to be an 'allow all' option for a folder. I would like to 'allow all' then subsequently lock the directory for certain file types to prevent malicious intent. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1470994 Permissions usually don't block file type. Just grant write access. You'll need to implement file type checking in your code.

Comment: Ah I see, well my code (client and server) already check for file type so that shouldn't be an issue. When you suggest 'grant write access' I cannot seem to actually do this, like I said, for 'all' users but I can on a user-by-user basis. Are you familiar with the 'Plesk' Control Panel? Admittedly, I am yet to look through the documentation so it could be something I'm overlooking. Cheers.

Comment: I believe the 'Plesk IIS WP User (IWPD_number(number))' will need to have write access. Thanks for your help guys, will try this out when I'm back home.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the server? I had the same problem and find out that when you publish a project , the empty folders don't created to the server. I recommend you either create manually the folder to the server if you have access or just put some file in the "Profiles" folder so to be created.

Comment: I solved my issue by adding write permissions to the 'Plesk IIS WP User (IWPD_number(number))' on the server folder.